# PHP: Remove line ending with ( and remove line starting with ) and grab second word of every line

Tags: php

I have a sample string as shown below. In the string, how can I remove line ending with ( and remove line starting with ) and grab second word of every line?

```
This is some text (
some more text,
one line text,
more and more text available,
this one is even longer and even more text is available,
) this is the last line;

This is also some more text (
Second time some more text,
one line text second time ,
Once again more and more text available,
finally this one is even longer and even more text is available,
) this is the last line;
```

The string shown above comes from a text file. Can be either pasted in a textarea or a file could be uploaded and this text will be read from the file. So in the example shown above, expected output is:

```
some more text,
one line text,
more and more text available,
this one is even longer and even more text is available,

Second time some more text,
one line text second time ,
Once again more and more text available,
finally this one is even longer and even more text is available,

//words are
more
line
and
one
time
line
again
this
```

How to do the above in PHP?

Comment: Have you done any research or wish just to get the complete solution?

Comment: What is the real-world application of this?

Comment: Look up the `preg_replace` function. `$` matches the end of a line and `^` matches the start of a line. `explode` might help you with getting to the second word of each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `explode`, `array_map`, and `array_filter` functions to do what you want.

First you have to define functions to filter out the ( and ) lines, and to extract the second word of each line.

```
function filter_line($line) {
    //the regular expression detects a line ending with a ( or beginning with a )
    if(preg_match('/(^\)|\($)/', trim($line))) return false;
    if(empty($line)) return false;
    return true;    
}

function map_line($line) {
    //the regular expression here splits the line into pieces at any whitespace
    //in case they used multiple spaces or a tab
    $split = preg_split('/\s+/', trim($line));

    //if there are one or zero words on this line then remove it from the result
    if(count($split) < 2) return false;

    //return the second word
    return $split[1];
}
```

Now that you have that, the rest is easy:

```
//this will split the whole text into an array of lines
$array = explode("\n", $myTextGoesHere);

//this will return an array of entries that are either the second word or false
$filtered = array_filter($array, 'filter_line');

//at this point $filtered contains the first step.
print_r($filtered);

//finally, this will extract the second word from each line
//and eliminate lines with less than two words
$result = array_filter(array_map('map_line', $filtered));

//$result contains the output
print_r($result);
```

All done.

Incidentally, it's clear you are trying to get type values from a `CREATE TABLE` statement - you might have to be a little more careful about how you parse that depending on your RDBMS.

Comment: This does give the words but gets rid of the 2 paragraphs of text completely.

Comment: I didn't realize you needed output at each step.

Comment: Ok figured that we need to do a print_r( $array ); to show the string.

Comment: I modified the solution so that you can get the output at each step.  Do you understand what's changed?  `array_filter` can also take a function which returns true or false to either include the line or remove it.  This is run first to just remove the lines that aren't wanted.  Then, `array_map` is called to extract the second word from each line, and `array_filter` is called one more time to remove any lines that didn't have at least two words (this may or may not be necessary depending on how consistent your input is)

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I think I do understand what is going on. And the lines of the paragraphs are stored in array but I can retrieve them and convert into string. Not a problem. Really appreciate all your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
//Assumes text is in $text

//Some preparations
$lines=explode("\n",$text);
$output=array();
$words=array();
$recording=false;

//Cycle lines
foreach ($lines as $line) {
  //Empty lines: Keep
  if ($line=='') {
    $output[]='';
    continue;
  }

  //Not recording: Wait for '('
  if (!$recording) {
    if (substr($line,-1)=='(') $recording=true;
    continue;
  }

  //Recording: Ending?
  if (substr($line,0,1)==')') {
    $recording=false;
    continue;
  }

  //Recording: Keep line
  $output[]=$line;

  //Recording: Keep 2nd word
  $line=preg_split('/\s+/', trim($line));
  if (sizeof($line)>1) $words[]=$line[1];
  //Remove next line if you want to ignore 1-word lines
  else $words[]='--no-second-word--';

}
```

Comment: Printing the $output & $words shows blank. Is something missing?

Comment: Just pasted it into PHP and working fine - did you populate $text as indicated in the first comment?

Comment: That's weird the way its behaving with me. Yes, I did assign the string to the $text variable and also used print_r($output); print_r($words); It just gave me this: Array ( [0] => ) Array ( )

Comment: +1. You are correct. It was missing \n. When I added them, it worked well.  I have already accepted another answer as solution & because I can't accept 2 solutions for the same question, I am voting your answer up. Thank you so much.